# Table printed from PDF on Ubuntu 16.04 has different sizes than defined

Tags: printing, libreoffice, pdf, epson

I have created a table in libreoffice writer as follows:
page settings:
A4 landscape, margins (left, right, top, bottom): 0mm, 0mm, 0mm, 0mm.

Table:
positioning:
from left: 0mm
from top: 0mm
from right: 27mm
from bottom: 10mm
6 cells, each of dimensions: 90mm width x 100mm height.

Dokument is printed from libreoffice writer to pdf.

After opening document in PDF, the sizes of cells (at least measured physically on the screen by physical ruler) seem to have same lengths.

However, after printing PDF, the sizes of the cells measured are as follows:
upper row size: ~99.5mm
lower row size: ~102.5mm
left column size: 88mm
middle and right columns sizes: 92mm

Dokument is printed on Epson WF-7710 with following settings:
A4 borderless, landscape, page scaling is off.

I've run out of options.
The problem is, the borderless printing directly from libreoffice doesn't work, so I am forced to workaround this problem by using printing from PDF document :(

Please, can anyone help me to find out what is wrong and where?

UPDATE:

```
A4 paper settings from PPD file:  
*PageSize A4/A4: "<</PageSize[595.20 841.68]/ImagingBBox null>>setpagedevice"
*PageSize TA4/A4 (Borderless): "<</PageSize[595.20 841.68]/ImagingBBox null>>setpagedevice"

*PageRegion A4/A4: "<</PageRegion[595.20 841.68]/ImagingBBox null>>setpagedevice"
*PageRegion TA4/A4 (Borderless): "<</PageRegion[595.20 841.68]/ImagingBBox null>>setpagedevice"

*ImageableArea A4/A4: "8.40 8.40 586.80 833.28"
*ImageableArea TA4/A4 (Borderless): "0.00 0.00 595.20 841.68"

*PaperDimension A4/A4: "595.20 841.68"
*PaperDimension TA4/A4 (Borderless): "595.20 841.68"
```

Comment: Something to do with the printable area on the printer?

Comment: I don't think so, since main problem is with different cell widths and heights on printed paper than defined in the document. But, I really don't know. I will get page settings from PPD file and paste in my question, so you can check. I don't know how to verify this. For me, printable area looks fine...

Comment: I've been waiting and thinking over a week and no clue. Please, is there someone who has got at least some idea what could be wrong with that printing?